# Mappings with counts at the end without using loops?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, count, map-operator

Suppose you are trying to create a set of mappings such that pressing `<C-t>` followed by a number `#` would alternate to the respective tab at index `#`. I know that using a loop, I can do:

```
" Map alt-x keys to jump to a tab
for i in range(1, 9)
  execute "nmap \<C-t>" . i . "> " . i . "gt"
endfor
```

Such a solution, however, hast the disadvantage of allowing only a mapping that recognizes up to 9. Is there a more general way to have a mapping depend on a count pressed **at the end** of the mapping, for instance such that hitting `<C-t>14` would focus tab number 14?

Note: the above is just an example, I am interested in this regardless of tabs per se.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with having a count at the end is Vim will have to wait to see if more keys are going to be pressed. E.g. `<c-t>1` might mean you are supplying a count of `1` or maybe it will end up being `14`.

The other problem is you have to make all these mappings. So if you want to support a count up to 15, then you need 15 mappings.

Options:

- Provide a terminating sequence. e.g. `<c-t>{count}<c-t>`. Still have to create lot of mappings, but it will allow for a "count"
- Simply use Vim's native `<count>` which is a proceeds the map sequence. e.g. `4gt`. This means one mapping and the count will work correctly.

#### Aside about tabs and buffers

Your mappings suggest a heavy tab centric workflow. I know it might sound weird but maybe try and use less tab panes together with a more buffers centric workflow. Here are some nice posts about it:

- [Why do Vim experts prefer buffers over tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26708822/438329)
- [Use buffers effectively!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21338192/438329)